# How to send Google Calendar invites from node.js using a sendgrid template?

Tags: node.js, gmail, google-calendar-api, sendgrid, icalendar

I'm trying to send `ics` calendar invites to users from node.js server with the goal of getting email clients (e.g. Gmail/Outlook etc) to render them as actual invites and not just usual file attachments.

This is very similar to what [Calend.ly](https://calendly.com/) does.

So, basically, I'm trying to get something like this in Gmail:

[image: invite screenshot]

---

The flow I need is the following (on the client-side):

1. In my frontend app User 1 presses the `schedule event` button;
2. User 2 presses `accept` button.
3. The event gets automatically scheduled and appears in both users google calendars (without any OAuth 2.0 stuff or anything like that. Just 2 button presses).
4. At the same time the users get emails with event details and the `.ics` file attachment. But the invites should already be in their calendars.

How can I do that?

If I need to use Google Calendar API for this, then how should I at least approach this if I can't have any OAuth 2.0 stuff for my users?

What I'm currently doing is I'm generating `.ics` files and sending them using `SendGrid`. However, with `.ics`s I can't achieve a result like in the image above. These `.ics` files are not invites, they are merely attachments.

---

So I was wondering how should I approach this at all? Is using Google Calendar API the right way to implement this? If yes, then how can it be done server-side-only without making users authenticate?

I know it's possible because Calendly does exactly this. Users just enter their emails into the input field, press `submit` and the event invites automatically appear in their Google calendars.

How could this be implemented?

Maybe I don't get something, but generating `.ics` files doesn't seem to do the trick, and at the same time Google Calendar API does not appear to be the solution as well because of OAuth2 authentication.

[In their docs they say](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth):

> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported.

---

Here's the code I'm using to send emails with `.ics` attachments (there's also a template on `SendGrid` side, hence the `dynamicTemplateData` prop):

```js
const SendGrid = require("@sendgrid/mail");

  const attachment = {
    filename: 'invite.ics',
    name: 'invite.ics',
    content: Buffer.from(data).toString('base64'),
    disposition: 'attachment',
    contentId: uuid(),
    type: 'text/calendar; method=REQUEST',
  };

SendGrid.send({
      attachments: [attachment],
      templateId,
      from: {
        email: config.emailSender,
        name: config.emailName,
      },
      to: user.email,
      dynamicTemplateData: {
        ...rest,
        user,
      },
      headers: {
        'List-Unsubscribe': `<mailto:unsubscribe.link`,
      },
    });
```

And here's how my `.ics` attachment files look like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Organization//Organization App//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20210420T180000Z
DTEND:20210420T190000Z
DTSTAMP:20210418T201735Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Denis Yakovenko:MAILTO:test+1@gmail.com
UID:25bb4d3e-b69d-46b0-baea-489c71c48c88
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=Denis Yakovenko;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:MAILTO:test+1@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=John Smith;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:MAILTO:test+2@gmail.com
CREATED:20210418T201735Z
DESCRIPTION:my description
LAST-MODIFIED:20210418T201735Z
LOCATION:https://virtual.location.com
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:my summary
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: can you share your node.js code that you're using to send the email with the ics attachment

Comment: @AbirTaheer Sure, I've updated the question

Answer (score 4):

I referenced [this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/1138) issue on the sendgrid repository as well as converted the solution from [the ruby version](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/issues/298#issuecomment-427443122) to javascript.

The following worked for me successfully and Google generated the event preview.

```js
const ics = require("ics");

const sendgrid = require("@sendgrid/mail");

const event = {
  start: [2018, 5, 30, 6, 30],
  duration: { hours: 6, minutes: 30 },
  title: "Bolder Boulder",
  description: "Annual 10-kilometer run in Boulder, Colorado",
  location: "Folsom Field, University of Colorado (finish line)",
  url: "http://www.bolderboulder.com/",
  geo: { lat: 40.0095, lon: 105.2669 },
  categories: ["10k races", "Memorial Day Weekend", "Boulder CO"],
  status: "CONFIRMED",
  busyStatus: "BUSY",
  organizer: { name: "Admin", email: "Race@BolderBOULDER.com" },
  attendees: [
    {
      name: "Adam Gibbons",
      email: "adam@example.com",
      rsvp: true,
      partstat: "ACCEPTED",
      role: "REQ-PARTICIPANT",
    },
  ],
};

const { value } = ics.createEvent(event);

sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

sendgrid.send({
  to: "email@example.com",
  from: "test@example.com",
  subject: "This is an example email 3",
  content: [
    {
      type: "text/plain",
      value: "Plain Content",
    },
    {
      type: "text/html",
      value: "HTML Content",
    },
    {
      type: "text/calendar; method=REQUEST",
      value: value,
    },
  ],
  attachments: [
    {
      content: Buffer.from(value).toString("base64"),
      type: "application/ics",
      name: "invite.ics",
      filename: "invite.ics",
      disposition: "attachment",
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: I saw a similar example in one of sendgrid github issue threads. But the problem with this is that I can't have the `content` array because I'm using dynamic templates. I tried to send this `content` array with just one element (`text/calendar; method=REQUEST`), which didn't work. Then I tried to send `content` with 2 elements: `text/calendar` and `application/json` for dynamicTemplateData. This didn't work either. And by "didn't work" I mean the email didn't get sent. It seems like it's either `dynamicTemplateData` or `content` properties, and I'm stuck with `dynamicTemplateData`

Comment: I removed the content array completely and only used the attachment, email was sent and rendered as calendar on gmail app but without rsvp.
The rsvp is what I am trying to get solution to and automatic addition to calendar.